Can a triggered ability of a permanent with shroud be targeted?
suppose Karlach, Fury of Avernus (with Lightning Greaves), triggers:

untap all attacking creatures. They gain first strike until end of turn. After this phase, there is an additional combat phase

in response, Voidslime to

counter target triggered ability

Question is: does the shroud of the source permanent extend to spells & abilities on the stack or can this just be countered?

Shroud has no effect on targeting abilities on the stack.
Shroud is defined in rule 702.18a:

Shroud is a static ability. “Shroud” means “This permanent or player can’t be the target of spells or abilities.”

The triggered ability on the stack is a separate object from the permanent that has shroud, so the ability can be targeted.
